# spf google configuration

Tags: bind, ubuntu-10.04, spf

I have a problem I can not solve.
I'm trying to setup my spf bind
I have a dedicated server Ubuntu.

I had put my configuration like this:

```
@ 28800 IN MX 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@ 28800 IN MX 3 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@ 28800 IN MX 3 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@ 28800 IN MX 5 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@ 28800 IN MX 5 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@ 28800 IN MX 5 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@ 28800 IN MX 5 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

@ 28800 IN TXT v = spf1 include: _spf.google.com ~ all
```

I stopped yesterday to today propagate.
Test this morning on the website "SPF Policy Tester"

But it gives the following message:

xxx.xx.x.xx may send in the name of the domain (the SPF policy was found).

I also asked my staff for hosting this setting include the cluster of them on google.
Because according to an acquaintance of mine who works with servers they need to release the range / 32

What would be the correct setting.

hug everyone.

Jansen

Answer (score 0):

This is the line I have in my bind configuration:

```
@                       IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

If you are also trying to include your dedicated host as an authorized sender you can try one of the following

```
"v=spf1 ip4:192.168.0.1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Where `192.168.0.1` is the address of your host.

```
"v=spf1 ip4:192.168.0.1/16 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Where is `192.168.0.1/16` is the range of IP addresses for the cluster.

```
"v=spf1 a:example.com include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Where the a record for `example.com` returns all the allowed IP addresses

Comment: Yep! I asked for them to put in the cluster hosting